# Facebook Graph API is returning empty data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Hello I'm trying to get the FB feed from a user profile on my webpage:
I'm using an app and the following is the code that I have tried:

```
<?php
//function to retrieve posts from facebook’s server

$token = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=zzzyyyxxx&grant_type=client_credentials';
$token = file_get_contents($token);
function loadFB($fbID){
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?limit=10";
    $url.= '&access_token=xxxxxx|TLd1z0EZNH1SD1VfA';// *
    $c = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $page = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
     var_dump($page);
     curl_close($c);
    if(isset($page->data)){
     return $page->data;}else{echo "aabrakadaabra";}
}

 $fbid = "myfbid";
 date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

 $myPosts = loadFB($fbid);

 foreach($myPosts as $dPost){
    if($dPost->from->id==$fbid){
         $dTime = strtotime($dPost->created_time);
         $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo($dPost->message) . $myTime; ?></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
 }
?>
```

Which is working fine, since I'm getting no error and to confirm the above I tried to see the feeds directly using the url below and it's returning empty data.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/myID/feed?&access_token=myToken
```

This is returning:

```
{
 "data": [

  ]
}
```

I have tried several other answers posted on SO, but non helped.

Comment: please specify your problem in a much more detailed way. is it a user profile? is it a page? are you using an app-, user- or page-token? what have you tried so far? what does the facebook docs say about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User profiles are not really made for using the feed on an external Website, but if you really want to do that you will have to use a User Access Token to access it. Authorize with the `read_stream` permission to get a User Access Token.

IMPORTANT: User Tokens are only valid for 60 days, after that you will have to refresh it. And you can´t do that automatically on your server.

Information about Authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

You can only access a User feed with a User token of that specific User.

Better solution: User a Page, you don´t need to authorize for that, you only need an App Access Token.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Ok, Thanks for explaining. Just one more query though, would the above post will work fine for a page?

Comment: as i said, for a page you would only need an app access token. take a look at the links i posted about the different tokens.

Comment: btw, that code of yours is weird. seems that you are trying to get a user token in a wrong way. take a look at the facebook docs if you want to know how to get a user token, you must authorize a user for that, you can´t just do that on the server. but you don´t use the first two lines of code anyway, you may just delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope 'read_stream' on login call of facebook.

Then use

`$this->facebook->setAccessToken('access_token');
$this->facebook->api('/user_id/feed');`

BUT feed will only disaply when user give you the permission to access data